# proving or disproving conditional convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Prove or disprove that if $\sum \frac{n a_n}{2^{n-1}}$  diverges then $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ could be conditionally convergent.

Where to start? I don't see the connection between those two series.

btw, how do I write An like in recursive series? didn't see that on any guide.

Thank You!

Comment: If $a_n$ converged to zero, $\sum \frac{n a_n}{2^{n-1}}$ would be convergent. So, we must have that $\lim a_n \ne 0$. Can you pick it up from here?

Comment: No, I don't see where your'e going with this. Could you please expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent, we must have that $\lim a_n = 0$. However, if this is the case, we also have that
$$
\left|\frac{n a_n}{2^{n-1}}\right|\leq \frac{M n}{2^{n-1}},
$$
which is convergent ($M$ is an upper bound for $|a_n|$). So, the conclusion is that claim is false.